# "Хочу селедку" или "хочу селедки"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно сказать: "хочу селедку" или "хочу селедки"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

От ситуации зависит.
Если поесть, то "селедки". Не уточняя, сколько и какую.  
Если купить в магазине, то "селедку". Вон ту, покрупнее, бочком лежит.